# How can I dynamically add/remove a button in a UIView and reposition the buttons below it and vertically resize the view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a UIView, defined in a nib, and I need to be able to show/hide a middle button in that view. When I show the button, I need to reposition the two bottom buttons below it, as well as make the view taller to make room for everything. When I hide the middle button, I need to move the two bottom buttons up and vertically resize the view to make it less tall. I do NOT need to animate any of this since it the changes will never occur while the view is visible to the user.

I'm new to iOS and I'm used to using Autolayout, but I can't use Autolayout in this case to handle this automatically, so my current approach is to hardcode the frame position and dimensions for the two bottom buttons for each of the two different situations. I'm also hardcoding the two different frame sizes for the view itself. In viewDidLoad, I determine if I need to show/hide the middle button and set the frames for the view and bottom buttons appropriately. This works, but if feels hacky. Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Without autolayout you can only change frames.

Comment: Your approach is common.  Nothing hacky about manually setting the origin and sizes of your views.  In fact, those of us that don't use interface builder (I don't) set them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hardcode your frame sizes in viewDidLoad. The only thing you should take care of is determining that whether you need to show you middle button or not. Within the implementation file where you are allocating your UIButtons, check if the middle button has to be shown, if Yes allocate it, if not then don't. The frames of two buttons and the view should contain a factor which can set/size them accordingly.

You'd basically be managing the Auto-layout programmatically. And if you're not even allowed to that then whatever else you'd end up doing would pretty much be a hack.

Comment: Thanks, user2099176, so if I understand you correctly, you're saying don't hardcode the frame values, but instead calculate them after I show/hide the middle button, in layoutSubviews? Same with the frame of the containing view?

Comment: Basically Yes. And I would suggest instead of calculating and setting the frames of the two buttons again, just set their frames in a way that they pick their proper positions automatically (again auto-layout). Although, just hiding the middle button wouldn't work as the other two would still read its frame. You would either have to set the frame to CGRectZero or not allocate the middle button altogether. The containing view would have to be resized since you can't get its size until all its subviews have been rendered.